# Actionscript 3 loading Chinese symbols into TextField using Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, video, video-streaming, cjk, interactive

I am having trouble loading Chinese Symbols into a TextField from another TextField.

I have a dynamic drop down box that loads its text from a string within the actionscript code, however the actionscript code cannot contain chinese symbols.

I thought the easiest way around this problem would be to load the text from another TextField, however it seems to appear blank, failing to load the text.

example

```
base1_mc.header1.textbox_txt.text=q1.text;
```

`base1_mc.header1.textbox_txt.text` = dynamic drop down textbox.
`q1.text` = chinese symbols inside TextField on the stage.

I thought this would have been a simple problem, however it doesnt appear to be so.

If I try to load it using this

```
base1_mc.header1.textbox_txt.text=q1;
```

it loads some text declaring a new and empty function.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off `embedFonts` for `TextField`.  I.E.:

```
textbox_txt.embedFonts = false.
```